# Storing Output of all tasks in one file in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm new to ansible so need small help.

I am having an ansible code in which i wanted to save output of each task in one file on each host. What i'm doing is creating a task and storing it's value in a file , so if i'm having 5 tasks which means there is 5 different files of each output . Can someone help me how i can save o/p of each task in same file on each destination server rather than storing in different.

```
- block:
  - name: CHECK LAST BOOT DEVICES!!!!
    command: sudo bootinfo -b
    register: output_of_LAST_BOOT
  - name: STORING LAST BOOT DEVICES INFO
    copy:
      content: "LAST BOOT DISK is - {{output_of_LAST_BOOT.stdout}} \n"
      dest: "/tmp/PATCH/LAST_BOOT.txt"
  - name: BOOTLIST BEFORE PATCHING
    command: sudo bootlist -m normal -o
    register: output_of_BOOTLIST_BEFORE
  - name: STORING O/P of BEFORE CHANGING BOOTLIST in file
    copy:
      content: "BOOTLIST BEFORE UPDATING ---------- \n \n {{output_of_BOOTLIST_BEFORE.stdout}} \n"
      dest: "/tmp/PATCH/BEFORE_BOOTLIST.txt"
```

Comment: The requirement is o/p of each task on each server, but on localhost .

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want is [fetch:](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/fetch_module.html#fetch-module), which conveniently will also store the files in a per-hostname subdirectory of the `dest:` option to `fetch`